# .Net Error(The data area passed to a system call is too small)

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ssis

Am trying to execute ssis package using dtexec utility from c# app(Creating New Process, assign arguments to Info and finally Process.start(),while processing have come accross
"The data area passed to a system call is too small" Error.
System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)

** Note:it is failing only when it exceeds certain number of arguments(In my case:22)(package variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Process object must have the UseShellExecute property set to false in order to use environment variables.